# Determining how many times a substring occurs in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to figure out how many times a string occurs in a string. For example:

```
nStr = '000123000123'
```

Say the string I want to find is 123. Obviously it occurs twice in nStr but I am having trouble implementing this logic into Python. What I have got at the moment:

```
pattern = '123'
count = a = 0
while pattern in nStr[a:]:
    a = nStr[a:].find(pattern)+1
    count += 1
return count
```

The answer it should return is 2. I'm stuck in an infinite loop at the moment.

I was just made aware that count is a much better way to do it but out of curiosity, does anyone see a way to do it similar to what I have already got?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> nStr = '000123000123'
>>> nStr.count('123')
2
```

A working version of your code:

```
nStr = '000123000123'
pattern = '123'
count = 0
flag = True
start = 0

while flag:
    a = nStr.find(pattern, start)  # find() returns -1 if the word is not found, 
    #start i the starting index from the search starts(default value is 0)
    if a == -1:          #if pattern not found set flag to False
        flag = False
    else:               # if word is found increase count and set starting index to a+1
        count += 1        
        start = a + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: count function doesn't work right in every situation. for example : pattern = "323" and nStr = "10032323000123". As you see 323 appears 2 times in the main string. But count's result is 1.  So the second solution is right.

Answer (score 36):

The problem with `count()` and other methods shown here is in the case of overlapping substrings.

For example: `"aaaaaa".count("aaa")` returns 2

If you want it to return 4 [`(aaa)aaa, a(aaa)aa, aa(aaa)a, aaa(aaa)`] you might try something like this:

```
def count_substrings(string, substring):
    string_size = len(string)
    substring_size = len(substring)
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(0,string_size-substring_size+1):
        if string[i:i+substring_size] == substring:
            count+=1
    return count

count_substrings("aaaaaa", "aaa")
# 4
```

Not sure if there's a more efficient way of doing it, but I hope this clarifies how `count()` works.

Comment: Note that xrange() was renamed to range() in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

```
import re

pattern = '123'

n =re.findall(pattern, string)
```

We can say that the substring 'pattern' appears len(n) times in 'string'.

Comment: This computes the count WITHOUT overlaps!

Comment: @BCuster good point. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75986864/8489363) which uses regex to compute the count WITH overlaps.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are searching how to solve this problem for overlapping cases.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghaklbob'
str = 'bob'
results = 0
sub_len = len(str) 
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:i+sub_len] == str: 
        results += 1
print (results)
```

Will result in 3 because: [azc(bob)obegghaklbob] [azcbo(bob)egghaklbob] [azcbobobegghakl(bob)]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new, but I think this is a good solution? maybe?

```
def count_substring(str, sub_str):
    count = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(str):
        if sub_str == str[i:i+2]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

string.count(substring) is not useful in case of overlapping.

My approach:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):

    length = len(string)
    counter = 0
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(length):
            if string[i:j+1] == sub_string:
                counter +=1
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing `a` with each loop. You should put:

```
a += nStr[a:].find(pattern)+1
```

...instead of:

```
a = nStr[a:].find(pattern)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_substring(string, substring):
         c=0
         l=len(sub_string)
         for i in range(len(string)):
                 if string [i:i+l]==sub_string:
                          c=c+1
         return c
string=input().strip()
sub_string=input().strip()

count= count_substring(string,sub_string)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @João Pesce and @gaurav, `count()` is not useful in the case of overlapping substrings, try this out...

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    c=0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if(string[i:i+len(sub_string)]==sub_string):
            c = c+1
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def countOccurance(str,pat):
    count=0
    wordList=str.split()
    for word in wordList:
        if pat in word:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually i'm using enumerate for this kind of problems:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
        count = 0
        for i, j in enumerate(string):
            if sub_string in string[i:i+3]:
                count = count + 1
        return count
```

Comment: @ruddy_simonpour you might have added that count_substring(nStr, pattern) with nStr = '000123000123' and pattern = '123' yields 2, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Only one approach here uses regex, and that approach doesn't work for overlaps.

Here is how to use regex with "lookaheads" to find overlapping matches also:

```
import re

nStr = '00012312310001231'
regex_pattern = '(?=(1231))'

matches = re.findall(regex_pattern, nStr)
print(len(matches))
```

This returns `3`, as it found two matches of `1231` in `1231231`, despite the overlap.

Answer (score -1):

def count(sub_string,string):

```
count = 0
ind = string.find(sub_string)

while True:
    if ind > -1:
        count += 1
        ind = string.find(sub_string,ind + 1)
    else:
        break
return count
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    len_sub = len(sub_string)
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if(string[i:i+len_sub] == sub_string):
            count+=1
    return count
```

Comment: What advantage does this offer over other answers?