# Better way in Python to count string in another string

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

This code works, but reading posts on here I get the impression it is probably not a very "Pythonic" solution.  Is there a better more efficient way to solve this specific problem:

What this code does: it counts instances of one string found in another and return the count.  It raises an error in case the user tries to pass in an empty string.

The version of the code I came up with but wondering if there is a better more efficient more "Pythonic" way to do this:

```
def count_string(raw_string, string_to_count):
    if len(string_to_count) == 0:
        raise ValueError("The length of string_to_count should not be 0!")
    else:
        str_count = 0
        string_to_count = string_to_count.lower()
        raw_string = raw_string.lower()
        if string_to_count not in raw_string:
            # this causes early exit if string not found at all
            return str_count
        else:
            while raw_string.find(string_to_count) != -1:
                indx = raw_string.find(string_to_count)
                str_count += 1
                raw_string = raw_string[(indx+1): ]
            return str_count
```

This code was written in Python 2.7 but should work in 3.x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining how many times a substring occurs in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476713/determining-how-many-times-a-substring-occurs-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: The "duplicate" contains useful feedback, bu the answers I am getting directly on this post are more specific and better solutions than can be found on the "duplicate" thread.  In short - I can see why this got flagged as a dupe, but I could not get the answer I needed from the other post.  I am getting the answers I was hoping for here and learning good stuff from this separate thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not use the `count` method of `str`?

```
>>> a = "abcghabchjlababc"
>>> a.count("abc")
3
```

Comment: I did not know about that one.  Thanks.  Going to give it a try.  I also see other methods on the "duplicate" flag link someone added but yours looks cleaner and shorter than even their approach.

Comment: The only difference is that an empty string would being you `len(a) + 1`. You can fix that by making a wrapper: `def count(a, b): return len(b) and a.count(b)` that will return 0 for that case.

Comment: Your solution does what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!  A quick question for my learning ... I am a little unclear about the logic of anding the count with the length to over come a zero length string as input.  How does that work?

Comment: When `len(b)` is positive the interpreter will move on and evaluate `a.count(b)` because of the `and` condition (progressive evaluation of boolean condition), otherwise, if the length is zero, then the and has no chance of getting true, and the first term, 0, is returned

Comment: You could use the easier to read `a.count(b) if len(b) else 0` instead

Comment: @Uriel I was just wondering why at the first place a.count(b) returned len(a)+1 if b is having zero length, any specific logic for returning len(a)+1.

Comment: @FarhanPatel my assumption is, because one could say that the empty space is anywhere between two letters (`len(a)-1` places), after the end (+1 place), and before the beginning (+1 place).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution.

```
>>> a= 'almforeachalmwhilealmleandroalmalmalm'
>>> len(a.split('alm')) - 1
6
>>> q = "abcghabchjlababc"
>>> len(q.split("abc")) - 1
3
```

Comment: This is a nicely creative solution too, but if after I revise code, I think that I will go with the string count method if it works.  That approach reads more like what it is.  This approach is good to know for other problems so thanks for posting it.

Comment: `O-O-O`  -> remove bounds (dashes). You'll get `O O O`.  How many bounds were there? Count of rings minus one -))