# Find the number of times a word occurs in a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

So for example if I want to know the number of times hello occurs in this word: `hellohellothere`, my code will give me `2` which is correct. But if I were to have `hellotherehello`, my code does not give me `2`, which means I think there is something wrong with my second for loop.

My code counts the number of letters in the string, and then I divide it by the length of the string to give how many times the string actually occurs, I don't think that really is the problem though.

here is the code.

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
find = input("Enter string to find")
count = int(0)

for x in range(0, len(word)-len(find)):
    if word[x] == find[0]:
        for i in range(0, len(find)):
            if word[x+i] == find[i]:
                count += 1
            else:  break

    count = count/len(find)

    print("Number of times it occurs is: ", count)
```

Comment: `word.count(find)`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way in Python to count string in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765930/better-way-in-python-to-count-string-in-another-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers recommend the string.count function, and that is how an experienced Python programmer with knowledge of the standard library would do it.  If I look at your approach, however, I see logic errors.

Your main loop has an off-by-one error.  The function `range(0, n)` iterates from 0 to n-1.  In the string 'hellotherehello' this will end the iteration one character before you get to the second occurrence of hello.  What you want is:

```
for x in range(0, len(word)-len(find) + 1):
```

You are trying to use the variable `count` for two different purposes: to count the number of successful matches, and to count characters one by one as you search for a match.  When you've already found one match and you begin to look for a second one, your `count` variable holds the value 1; until you find the first match it's 0.  Much better is to test the characters one at a time for FAILURE rather than SUCCESS, and use Python's `for:else:` construct.  Inside the loop you will have this:

```
if word[x] == find[0]:
    for i in range(0, len(find)):
        if word[x+i] != find[i]:
            break
    else:
        count += 1
```

Good luck with learning Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that it thinks 'he' in the word 'there' is the beginning of hello and counts towards count.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in function for this: [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

```
print("Number of times it occurs is: ", word.count(find))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good answer to your question is to use a nested for loop but you word is One word i.e `hellohellothere`, JavaScript sees it as one word ,but if it’s written like this `hello hello there` or `hello there hello` have a solution for you

```
Let words = “hello there hello’;
Let arrayWords = words.split(“ ”);
Let countWords = “”;

For(let i = 0; i < arrayWords.length; i++){
          Let count = 0;
    For(let j = 0; j < arrayWords.length; j++){
           If(arrayWords[i] === arrayWords[j]){
                count ++;
             countWords = arrayWords[i]
      }
   }
 Console.log(~${countWords} appeared ${count} time;
 }
```