# count an occurrence of a string in a bigger string

Tags: python

I am looking to understand what I can do to make my code to work. Learning this concept will probably unlock a lot in my programming understanding. I am trying to count the number of times the string `'bob'` occurs in a larger string. Here is my method:

```
s='azcbobobegghakl'

for i in range(len(s)):
    if (gt[0]+gt[1]+gt[2]) == 'bob':
       count += 1
       gt.replace(gt[0],'')
    else:
       gt.replace(gt[0],'')

print count
```

How do I refer to my string instead of having to work with integers because of using `for i in range(len(s))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way in Python to count string in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765930/better-way-in-python-to-count-string-in-another-string)

Comment: strings are iterable in python. `for c in 'abc':` will yield, a, b, c in order

Comment: Your indentation is (probably) off since I can't imagine that you want the `else` clause to go with the `for` loop as opposed to the `if` statement inside the loop, although it is somewhat hard to figure out what you are trying to do. Are you trying to destroy the string in the process of counting how many times another string occurs in it?

Comment: This question is likely to be soon closed as a duplicate -- but note that `gt[0:3]` (or simply `gt[:3]`) is the same as `gt[0]+gt[1]+gt[2]`. You can use *slices* to extract substrings from the string. `gt[i:i+3]` will be the 3-element substring starting at index `i`

Comment: Yes my indentation was wrong. I just changed it. What i am trying to do is the go through the first 3 letters and and remove the very first letter  and remove the first string. Every time the combination of the first 3 strings= 'bob' then it increase my 'count' variable

Comment: Also consider `re.findall`

Comment: can you have these matches overlap? in your example, do you want bob found once or twice?

Comment: once. But the right answer is supposed to be 2. but I think I now know what to do. My code is currently giving 0, if i use 'in' in an another code I have that bob once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks. your support help to birth the answer in. here what I have :

```
  numBobs = 0
  for i in range(1, len(s)-1):
      if s[i-1:i+2] == 'bob':
          numBobs += 1
  print 'Number of times bob occurs is:', numBobs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def number_of_occurrences(needle, haystack, overlap=False):
    hlen, nlen = len(haystack), len(needle)

    if nlen > hlen:
        return 0 # definitely no occurrences

    N, i = 0, 0

    while i < hlen:
        consecutive_matching_chars = 0
        for j, ch in enumerate(needle):
            if (i + j < hlen) and (haystack[i + j] == ch):
                consecutive_matching_chars += 1
            else:
                break

        if consecutive_matching_chars == nlen: 
            N += 1

            # if you don't need overlap, skip 'nlen' characters of 'haystack'
            i += (not overlap) * nlen # booleans can be treated as numbers

        i += 1

    return N
```

Example usage:

```
haystack = 'bobobobobobobobobob'
needle = 'bob'

r = number_of_occurrences(needle, haystack)
R = haystack.count(needle)

print(r == R)
```

Comment: I think it'd be very useful to add a detailed explanation for OP

Comment: Not quite what I EXPECTED