# How to assign two values in for loop variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can we use for loop to assign two values from the string like following

```
string="abcd"
for i in string:
      print(i)
```

this will give i one value from the string

```
#output
a
b
c
d
```

how can i take two values like ab and cd. I know we can do this in print but i need to assign two values in "i"
I need output

```
#output
ab
cd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string = "abcd"
for i in range(1,len(string),2):
    print(string[i-1]+string[i])
```

Output:

```
ab
cd
```

**Explanation**

You can modify the range function to start at index 1 and go all the way through `len(string)` in steps of 2(`range(1,len(string),2)`)

Then inside the loop, since we start index 1, we print `string[i-1]` and concatenate with `string[i]`

Answer (score 3):

You could use list-comprehension like the following:

```
n = 2
s = "abcd"
res = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
print(res) # ['ab', 'cd']
```

This is applicable to any `n`th place.

If its only 2 chars that you are after you can also use regex, but if it for any `n` its not convenient, an example for `n=2` is:

```
import re
s = "abcd"
res = re.findall('..?',s)
print(res) # ['ab', 'cd']
```

Comment: @SaadJillani this is a different question, that is unrelated to the one asked here. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476713/determining-how-many-times-a-substring-occurs-in-a-string-in-python where you will find a way to calculate it without any method used.